# ¿Como recibo variables en Web2py?

Tags: web2py

Estoy comenzando con este framework necesito ayuda para hacer una calculadora pero necesito saber como capturar una variable

Comment: Bienvenido, le sugiero que haga el [tour] y vea [ask]. Adjunte el código de lo que ha intentado hasta ahora para que la pregunta sea bien recibida. Saludos

Comment: si amigo lo que pasa que solo necesito saber como capturar variables en web2py con eso podria hacer la calculadora

Comment: si me podrias ayudar'

Comment: El tema es que este sitio no funciona de la forma en que tal vez estás esperando, la idea aquí, es que se plantean problemas de forma más especifica aportando en lo posible todo el código de lo que se hubiera intentado hacer. Tal vez alguien te responda, pero normalmente estas preguntas terminan cerrándose por ser demasiado amplias. Saludos.

Comment: amplias? solo quiero saber como obtener un dato de una variable para continuar mi trabajo si me pueden ayudar por favor

Answer (score 1):

Te voy a explicar como sumar 2 números, de ahí podrás hacer la calculadora que quieras

primero crea una función en tu `Controller`, ejemplo:

```
def Sumar():
    num1=0
    num2=0
    if request.post_vars:
        num1=float(request.post_vars.num1)
        num2=float(request.post_vars.num2)
        total=num1+num2
     return locals()
```

y en tu **`view`** crea un formulario con dos campos con el **`name=num1`** y **`name=num2`** y *button* de tipo **`Submit`**, acuérdate de crear el **HTML** con el nombre de la función en este caso suma

Answer (score 0):

Puedes acceder a las variables tal y como lo hacías ya en python. Tienes algunas variables de web2py a las que puedes acceder en todo momento. 
Para por ejemplo acceder a la id del usuario logueado: auth.user.id
Para mas información te recomiendo que te leas el libro de web2py, donde se aclararan todas tus dudas.

Si quieres capturar un campo de formulario: request.vars.nombredelcampo o name_form.vars.nombreelcampo